# SEDE Tutorial does not have a tab title

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, window-title

The [new tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) does not have a `<title>` attribute in the `<head>` of the HTML:

[image: tab displays the url of the tutorial]

My browser dev tools are telling me that it does have a `<title>` tag, but it is empty. This seems to be the case on all of the tutorial pages.

I am using Firefox 47.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote the code to make this happen and sent in a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/79), which has been merged. Presumably it'll go live along with the next deploy.

Answer (score 8):

Good eye! This is slated to be fixed in an upcoming minor update, along with slightly improved help UI.

Comment: A couple of months later and this still hasn't been fixed, do you have a status update or has it fallen through your radar?

Comment: I'm sorry, it had indeed fallen off our radar. Thanks for the ping!

Comment: Since Art's fix (in the answer below) has been merged, does this get [status-completed] now?